# How to make a list from a range within a dataframe?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I am trying to create a list from a dataframe from a range.

Here is my column of strings:

```
df['ID'] =['' ,'2','4', '','8', '','16-18','25', '30-31']
#spaces with no values represent null
```

I would like to create an output like this:

```
df['ID'] = [' ', 'ID 2', 'ID 4', 'ID 8',' ', ['ID 16','ID 17', 'ID 18'],
              'ID 25',['ID 30','ID 31']]
```

Can someone please help?

Answer (score 0):

IIUC

```
df.ID.str.split('-').apply(lambda x : x[0] if len(x)<=1 else list(range(int(x[0]),int(x[1])+1)))
Out[182]: 
0                
1               2
2               4
3                
4               8
5                
6    [16, 17, 18]
7              25
8        [30, 31]
Name: ID, dtype: object
```

Comment: thanks, but I get the error:  TypeError: object of type 'float' has no len()

Answer (score 0):

#### Setup

```
df = pd.DataFrame()
df['ID'] =[ np.nan, 2,4, np.nan,8, np.nan ,'16-18',25, '30-31']
```

Then first build your `"ID"` for the ranges

```
s = df.ID.str.split("-")
s2 = s[s.notna()].apply(lambda x: ("ID "+pd.Series(list(range(int(x[0]), int(x[1])+1))).astype(str)).tolist())
```

and then for the regular cases (except NaNs and ranges)

```
non_na = df.ID[df.ID.notna()]
non_na_range = non_na[~non_na.index.isin(s2.index)]
s3 = "ID " + non_na_range.astype(str)
```

Then assign

```
df.loc[s2.index, "ID"] = s2
df.loc[s3.index, "ID"] = s3
```

Output

```
    ID
0   NaN
1   ID 2
2   ID 4
3   NaN
4   ID 8
5   NaN
6   [ID 16, ID 17, ID 18]
7   ID 25
8   [ID 30, ID 31]
```

Comment: Everything runs well unti I get to the last line. I get thsi error: ValueError: cannot reindex from a duplicate axis. Also, all of my values from my ID column in my df is a string and not a float or int.

Comment: first line outputs nan for all values and does not split the string